# Sorting in dd/mm/yyyy format group by date

Tags: sql-server, group-by, order-by

```
select 
    CONVERT(nvarchar(15),TransDate,103) as TransDate,
    isnull(SUM(Convert(int,Amount)),'0') as Amount 
from HMS_DiagnosisTransactions 
where TransDate between '05/01/2015' and '07/24/2015' 
group by CONVERT(nvarchar(15),TransDate,103) 
order by CONVERT(nvarchar(15),TransDate,103;
```

it is showing like `20/05/2015,20/06/2015,21/05/2015,22/07/2015`
but i want `20/05/2015,21/05/2015,20/06/2015,22/07/2015`

```
TransDate   Amount
01/06/2015  47445
02/05/2015  214
02/06/2015  4800
03/06/2015  55043
03/07/2015  0
04/06/2015  46055
05/05/2015  250
05/06/2015  29890
06/06/2015  10680
08/05/2015  4560
08/06/2015  100
09/06/2015  11150
10/06/2015  15740
11/05/2015  700
11/06/2015  6070
13/05/2015  3350
16/05/2015  15300
17/05/2015  0
17/06/2015  500
18/05/2015  0
19/05/2015  10550
20/05/2015  1300
20/06/2015  0
21/05/2015  1000
21/07/2015  11250
22/05/2015  6260
22/06/2015  16041
22/07/2015  1300
23/05/2015  60
23/07/2015  1850
24/05/2015  6104
24/06/2015  9271
25/05/2015  117891
25/06/2015  0
26/05/2015  74545
26/06/2015  6470
27/05/2015  2750
27/06/2015  7400
29/06/2015  700
30/05/2015  65035
30/06/2015  1300
```

Comment: Why do you want to show `01/06/2015`? Aren't you concerned that some people will see January 6th and others will see June 1st? Your query even uses m/d/y but presents data as d/m/y. That is confusing (is the start of your range Jan 5 or May 1?). What is the data type of `Amount` and why do you have to convert it to an `int`?

Comment: And get rid of the quotes around your zero. That's not meant to be a string.

Answer (score 2):

You should always use the schema prefix, avoid using sketchy `BETWEEN` for date range queries, and try not to force regional and ambiguous date formats like d/m/y or m/d/y. Your main problem, though, is that you're intentionally ordering by a string representation of a date, with day first. This means that all of the firsts (regardless of month or year) will sort before all of the seconds, thirds, etc. I highly recommend just:

```
SELECT TransDate = CONVERT(DATE, TransDate),
       Amount = COALESCE(SUM(Amount), 0)
FROM dbo.HMS_DiagnosisTransactions 
WHERE TransDate >= '20150501' AND TransDate < '20150725'
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, TransDate)
ORDER BY TransDate;
```

If you really want to present the data as `dd/mm/yyyy` (again, I recommend against that, since it is ambiguous), do that at the presentation layer, not in SQL. If you can't do it in the presentation tier, then:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
   SELECT TransDate = CONVERT(DATE, TransDate),
          Amount = COALESCE(SUM(Amount), 0)
  FROM dbo.HMS_DiagnosisTransactions 
  WHERE TransDate >= '20150501' AND TransDate < '20150725'
  GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, TransDate)
)
SELECT TransDate = CONVERT(CHAR(10), TransDate, 103), Amount
FROM x
ORDER BY x.TransDate;
```

Some suggested reading:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [Mis-handling date/range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)
- [Avoiding the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)
- [FORMAT() is nice and all, but...](http://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)

Comment: Order by x.TransDate in that last example, because otherwise you're ordering by the output column

Comment: @Rob you're right, I meant to give it a different alias inside the CTE.